# javafx - How to set selected row text color in not focused TableView

Tags: css, javafx-2

My app uses row selection mode (`table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false)`)

In my CSS:

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
   -fx-background-color: steelblue; 
   -fx-text-fill: red !important;
}
```

property `-fx-background-color` works fine, but `-fx-text-fill` does not. The text color of selected row is black (if `TableView` is not focused) or white (if `TableView` is focused).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This works for me, though there may be easier ways:

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
   -fx-background-color: steelblue; 
}
.table-row-cell:selected .text {
       -fx-fill: red ;

}
```

Comment: Did you applied the style to the table? Or to the row? And how have you done it?

Comment: It's an external style sheet. See the [standard JavaFX tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm#CHDGHCDG) section on CSS.

Comment: Is there a way to do it on the `tableView.setRowFactory()` method?

Comment: Well, probably, but it would be pretty complicated. The recommended approach for this is CSS. `TableRow` has `isSelected()`, `setTextFill(...)`, and `setBackground(...)` methods that could be used, but you would have to carefully observe the `selectedProperty()` and make sure everything was updated correctly.

Comment: Hello James_D. Not sure if you're ever gonna get to read my comment but I just wanted to say thank you so much for your contribution to this website. Saw your amazing answers a dozen times already in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 4):

For JavaFX 8, based on the Modena stylesheet, the selected row text color is based on the brightness of the background (white for dark backgrounds, black for light backgrounds). I've been able to override this by setting the text background color directly (which then gets used for the text color for selected rows):

```
.table-row-cell:selected {
   -fx-background-color: steelblue; 
   -fx-text-background-color: red;
}
```